# Getting wrong results from counting function

Tags: python, json, dictionary, cluster-computing, geocoding

Here is my code, i know it isn't clean enough, but it cannot run as I thought, anyone can help me?

I fixed it, thank you for your helps

**The general idea of this code is comparing each coordinate with a range, and calculate the amounts of points for each grid**

the result is:
{'other': 862, 'B4': 2, 'D5': 1, 'A1': 0, 'D4': 2, 'A3': 2, 'A2': 2, 'A4': 0, 'B2': 36, 'B3': 8, 'C3': 15, 'C2': 50, 'C1': 1, 'C4': 7, 'D3': 4, 'C5': 1, 'B1': 7}

**I don't know why 'other' get so much**

```
 import json
    from pprint import pprint
    xa1_min = 144.700000
    xa1_max = 144.850000
    ya1_min = -37.650000
    ya1_max = -37.500000

    xa2_min = 144.850000
    xa2_max = 145.000000
    ya2_min = -37.650000
    ya2_max = -37.500000

    xa3_min = 145.000000
    xa3_max = 145.150000
    ya3_min = -37.650000
    ya3_max = -37.500000

    xa4_min =145.150000
    xa4_max =145.300000
    ya4_min =-37.650000
    ya4_max =-37.500000

    xb1_min =144.700000
    xb1_max =144.850000
    yb1_min =-37.800000
    yb1_max =-37.650000

    xb2_min =144.850000
    xb2_max =145.000000
    yb2_min =-37.800000
    yb2_max =-37.650000

    xb3_min =145.000000
    xb3_max =145.150000
    yb3_min =-37.800000
    yb3_max =-37.650000

    xb4_min =145.150000
    xb4_max =145.300000
    yb4_min =-37.800000
    yb4_max =-37.650000

    xc1_min =144.700000
    xc1_max =144.850000
    yc1_min =-37.950000
    yc1_max =-37.800000

    xc2_min =144.850000
    xc2_max =145.000000
    yc2_min =-37.950000
    yc2_max =-37.800000

    xc3_min =145.000000
    xc3_max =145.150000
    yc3_min =-37.950000
    yc3_max =-37.800000

    xc4_min =145.150000
    xc4_max =145.300000
    yc4_min = -37.950000
    yc4_max = -37.800000

    xc5_min =145.300000
    xc5_max =145.450000
    yc5_min =-37.950000
    yc5_max =-37.800000

    xd3_min =145.000000
    xd3_max =145.150000
    yd3_min =-38.100000
    yd3_max =-37.950000

    xd4_min =145.150000
    xd4_max =145.300000
    yd4_min =-38.100000
    yd4_max =-37.950000

    xd5_min =145.300000
    xd5_max =145.450000
    yd5_min =-38.100000
    yd5_max =-37.950000
    #["properties"]['ID']
    # Reading from grid
    with open('tinyTwitter.json') as load_f:
        info = json.load(load_f)

    coordinates = list()
    #print info

    for line in info:
        #print line['json']['coordinates']['coordinates']
        coordinates.append(line['json']['coordinates']['coordinates'])

    #print coordinates[0][1]
    #print coordinates[0][0]

    counts = {'A1':0,'A2':0,'A3':0,'A4':0,'B1':0,'B2':0,'B3':0,'B4':0,'C1':0,'C2':0,'C3':0,'C4':0,'C5':0,'D3':0,'D4':0,'D5':0,'other':0}
    #comparing
    def compare(x,y):


    if xa1_min <= x <= xa1_max and ya1_min <= y <= ya1_max:
        counts['A1'] +=1

    elif xa2_min <= x <= xa2_max and ya2_min <=y<= ya2_max:
        counts['A2'] +=1

    elif xa3_min <= x <= xa3_max and ya3_min <=y<= ya3_max:
        counts['A3'] +=1

    elif xa4_min <= x <= xa4_max and ya4_min <=y<= ya4_max:
        counts['A4'] += 1

    elif xb1_min <= x <= xb1_max and yb1_min <=y<= yb1_max:
        counts['B1'] += 1

    elif xb2_min <= x <= xb2_max and yb2_min <=y<= yb2_max:
        counts['B2'] += 1

    elif xb3_min <= x <= xb3_max and yb3_min <=y<= yb3_max:
        counts['B3'] += 1

    elif xb4_min <= x <= xb4_max and yb4_min <=y<= yb4_max:
        counts['B4'] += 1

    elif xc1_min <= x <= xc1_max and yc1_min <=y<= yc1_max:
        counts['C1'] += 1

    elif xc2_min <= x <= xc2_max and yc2_min <=y<= yc2_max:
        counts['C2'] += 1

    elif xc3_min <= x <= xc3_max and yc3_min <=y<= yc3_max:
        counts['C3'] += 1

    elif xc4_min <= x <= xc4_max and yc4_min <=y<= yc4_max:
        counts['C4'] += 1

    elif xc5_min <= x <= xc5_max and yc5_min <=y<= yc5_max:
        counts['C5'] += 1

    elif xd3_min <= x <= xd3_max and yd3_min <=y<= yd3_max:
        counts['D3'] += 1

    elif xd4_min <= x <= xd4_max and yd4_min <=y<= yd4_max:
        counts['D4'] += 1

    elif xd5_min <= x <= xd5_max and yd5_min <=y<= yd5_max:
        counts['D5'] += 1

    else:
        counts['other']+= 1

        #print counts

    for i,j in coordinates:
        #print i,j
        compare(i,j)
    print counts
```

Comment: clearly, 0+0 = 0

Comment: I suspect your remaining issue may have to do with your nested `if`s. An `elif` attached to a top level `if` won't be checked if the previous inner `if` failed. You may want to combine your `x` and `y` conditions with `and` instead of nesting `if` statements. You can also simplify things a lot with chained comparisons like `xa1_min < x < xa1_max`. I'd also suggest doing something to combine the many min and max variables you have into some kind of data structure that you can iterate over (without so much repeated code).

Comment: there are still some issues to conduct incorrect results

Comment: @Blckknght thank you for your advices, I have modified as your words, but there are still some issues that I get some strange results and look like incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for:

```
len(counts.keys())
```

If not, some more context surrounding your problem would help to find a solution. Also, it looks like you could save quite a bit of code repetition by storing those min/max data points in a list of dictionaries and condense those comparison statements into a single loop. Something along the lines of:

```
data = [{'x-min': 0, 'x-max': 1, 'y-min': 0, 'y-max': 1, 'count': 0}, ...]

def within_threshold(x1, y1, point):
    within_x = x >= point['x-min'] and x <= point['x-max']
    within_y = y >= point['y-min'] and y <= point['y-max']
    return within_x and within_y

def compare(x, y):
    for point in data:
        if within_threshold(x, y, point):
            point['count'] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the lines of the form

```
counts['A1']+=counts['A1']
```

with lines of the form

```
counts['A1']+=1
```

As it is, you never increment `counts` because you're adding its current value (0) to it each time.